# django modules to handle recurring subscription?

Tags: django, subscription

i need to include subscription/recurring billing in my web app that was designed in django.

so here's a short description of what i want:

A person signs up for free initially and is able to do whatever he wants within 24 hours after which he has to decide if he wants to upgrade, there are three options:

GOLD, SILVER, PlATINUM.

This will be a recurring monthly payment.

I have already gotten django-paypal installed so i was wondering if there is anything that can handle the subscriptions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply assign a level to each user, and modify this according to their choice of upgrade. I assume you are already storing the date of upgrade.

Then you simply need to set up a scheduled task using either cron or [Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/) to regularly process the actual payments.

Django's included django.contrib.auth app also has built-in groups and permissions functionality which may be helpful to you (see the official docs for more info).

[Userena](http://django-userena.org/) may also be worth a look.

A separate approach that might work for you might be to use Paypal's subscription options, as detailed in this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488947/1275237